# VSTS and InstallShield projects

Tags: azure-devops, installshield

I am currently investigating migration from TFS to VSTS. The one issue I can't seem to find an answer for is whether there would be a way for us to build our installshield projects in VSTS. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of TFS are you currently using? Are you talking about building them on the VSTS hosted agent, or on a private agent?

Comment: TFS version wouldn't matter.  Private agent would be required for InstallShield.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter It would matter if he's using XAML build.

Comment: In what way would it matter? I don't see how.  Regardless of what build framework he uses he's ultimately going to need to shell out to IsCmdBld or MSBbuild the SLN on a private agent running as a service account with admin privs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InstallShield requires a private build server.  You can't use the hosted build servers because InstallShield isn't installed.  It can't be XCOPY pulled in, requires admin  to be installed and has a license.key DRM scheme tied to the MAC address.

WiX works better on the hosted servers but still isn't perfect because you have to disable MSI validation.  Validation requires admin rights or it fails.

Other then this limitation, I've migrated many TFS environments to VSTS and it'll work just fine with InstallShield.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher! I was assuming as much. Only makes sense.

Comment: Does that mean I can't use InstallShield in azure?

Comment: My most recent use of Azure build servers suggest to me that half of the problem is solved.  You now have Admin rights so you could install the build server as part of your pipeline every time.   However your MAC address is going to always be different so I think you'd have a license activation problem to solve.  I'd ask InstallShield support.  Perhaps @Michael Urman can answer.